# How to remove a hidden field array using jquery

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I have this as hidden values for a form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="times[]" value='{"date" : "April 12, 2012"}' />
<input type="hidden" name="times[]" value='{"date" : "April 13, 2012"}' />
<input type="hidden" name="times[]" value='{"date" : "April 14, 2012"}' />
```

Using jquery, how could I create a link that when clicked it could remove a hidden form field above? So say I click a link and I want that click to remove the second hidden form field above, how could I do that?

Comment: Will the value be a general json string, or will it always only have the "date" field?

Comment: @joeframbach It will be a json string that will hold more than just the date. Actually it will hold 8 different values for each hidden field.

Comment: I figured. I've provided a more general-purpose function then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create -

```
   var $ip = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'yourid',
    name: 'yourname',
   value: 'yourvalue' 
})
$(ip).appendTo('body');
```

Then to remove -You can add this in any click event ..

```
$ip.remove();
```

To remove all hidden fields try this.You can add this in any click event ..

```
$("input[type='hidden']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general-purpose function you can use to remove elements that match a json-encoded value.

Call it with `removeByJsonValue(':hidden',{date:"April 13, 2012"});`

```
removeByJsonValue(selector, data) { // data = {key:value, ...}
    $(selector).each(function(element) {
        var element_data = $.parseJSON($(element).val());
        var remove = true;
        $(data).each(function(key,value) {
            if (element_data[key] != value) {
                remove = false;
            }
        });
        if (remove) {
            $(element).remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have exactly three hidden fields and in that exact order, you can do

```
$('input[type=hidden]:eq(1)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vGLSd/

`eq` documentation http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

`remove()` documentation http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 0):

if you have a link as below:

```
<a href="#" id="remove">remove hidden</a>
```

your jquery code would be

```
$("#remove").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($("input[name='times[]']").eq(1).val());
    $("input[name='times[]']").eq(1).remove();
});
```

link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LUtSp/